# Opening a div on mouse over and staying open until mouse is moved out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have my markup like this:

```
<div class="wrapper-header">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class=""><a href="#" class="toggle">Show Categories</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-categories">
<div class="container">
Content Here
</div>
</div>
```

The `.wrapper-categories` is `display: none;` by default, so it only shows once clicked with:

```
 $(".toggle").on('click', function (event){
               event.preventDefault();
               $(".wrapper-categories").slideToggle("fast");
                 $(this).html(function(i,html) {
                     if (html.indexOf('Browse') != -1 ){
                        html = html.replace('Show','Hide');
                     } else {
                        html = html.replace('Hide','Show');
                     }
                     return html;
                 });
             });
```

Now, I'd like to change that to showing on `hover` instead of on `click`, with the `.wrapper-categories` staying open if someone moves their mouse over and closing if it's not on the link or the content div anymore.

I tried replacing changing it to `$(".toggle").hover(function() {` and that worked, but it's not staying open. What else must I do?

Comment: can you give a fiddle plz?

Comment: Will post one shortly, yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working the way you desire is because the hover event of `.toggle` works only for itself. As soon as you try to move the mouse cursor over its **contents** i.e, under `.wrapper-categories`, the cursor goes out of the .toggle scope.

Here's a working example of how you need to implement this. You need to slightly change the structure of the menu you want to create using a simple structure of **ul** and **li**.

Here's is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vmukLbLg/1/).

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="menu"><a href="#" class="toggle">Show Categories</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Content Here
        </li>
        <li>
            Content Here
        </li>
        <li>
            Content Here
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**:

```
$(".menu").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');    
});
$(".menu").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.menu > ul{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.menu > ul > li:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That makes sense but unfortunately because of the structure of the website, I cannot move the two separate wrappers or the content inside of it. They must remain separate wrappers.

Comment: OK. Then I guess it is possible with onClick only. Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/44wrL4g4/2/

I wrapped all in a `menu` class.

And I have used `mouseleave()` instead of `mouseout()`. See the Jquery documentation for these functions.

See the code for further understanding.